# ::1 during exim-config?

Tags: networking, exim

While executing

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config
```

there is this screen (IP adresses on which exim shall listen):
[image]

What does the ::1 mean? Is it an exim specific thing or - as I assume - some genereal linxu thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::1` is an IPv6 address for localhost.  Numerically, the address is just 1.